# How to post on user's wall indicating an app was installed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ doesn't seem to give a clue about it. Would "Install(ed)" be an action? If the feed is something like " installed  on iPhone", how to make the  to be a link such that the user can tap on it so to lead the user to App Store?

I know the API to use, something like the following. But I just don't know what are the  params that should be there for the above feed.

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1]
    [params setObject:username forKey:@"name"];
    [params setObject:@"Description" forKey:@"description"];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
                         andParams:params 
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                       andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: When you post on users wall, It posts using the Application which you used to post on users wall.

Comment: ah, seems see it before. Would it be ok to share an example? Screenshot or what does the full feed message look like?

Comment: You can get all info of setting the facebook ios sdk with a screenshot of a post.. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Comment: hey tom, if this is true. please mark it correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all info of setting the facebook ios sdk with a screenshot of a post..

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build